# Фиксированный горизонтальный экран SFML

Tags: android, c++, sfml

Можно ли отображать программу постоянно только в горизонтальном положении в SFML? Извините за возможно глупый вопрос, но я ответа на него так и не нашел :(

Answer (score 0):

Это следует прописать в манифесте приложения как аттрибут активити:

```
 <activity ... android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Comment: а что делать если нет файла манифеста? его нужно создать вручную? Если да, можешь пожалуйста объяснить как, буду благодарен

Comment: Его не может не быть, без манифеста андроид приложение просто не соберется.