# Как сделать альбомную ориентацию в играх?

Tags: c++, android, sfml, orientation

Я собираюсь делать игру на библиотеки sfml на c++, хотелось бы узнать, как это возможно реализовать? Я хочу, чтобы сразу при заходе в игру экран поворачивался на 90 градусов, соответственно, чтобы шторка уведомлений тоже переместилась, как в играх. Я бы хотел делать игру для телефона (и на телефоне(не спрашивайте)), что-то читал про манифесты, но я в этом полный 0, есть ли какие-то легкие способы?

Comment: *"но походу все библиотеки для игр не поддерживают поворот экрана"* - это очень смелое утверждение! Настолько смелое, что очевидно неверное :-)

Comment: Да, я понял, что написал глупость, у меня слишком мало опыта, но я работал с 3 библиотеками и ни в одном не было такого(

Comment: Наверняка было, просто вы не нашли. Попробуйте конкретизировать вопрос, типа "Как задать альбомную ориентацию в %название_движка%?"

Comment: Причём это наверняка дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1442522